# Neo4jClient System.NullReferenceException

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

some times in Neo4jClient I got this error. I try to investigation whats the problem but I don't found any reason. Does any one have the same problem or can help me?

Thanks

{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.","ExceptionType":"System.NullReferenceException","StackTrace":"   at 
Neo4jClient.GraphClient.Neo4jClient.IRawGraphClient.ExecuteGetCypherResults[TResult](CypherQuery query) in D:\temp\9517fa3\Neo4jClient.Shared\GraphClient.cs:line 919\r\n   at 
Mandarim.Storage.Neo4j.Manager.ManagerBase`1.GetNodesRelatedOrderBy(String match, String id, String relationNodeType, String propertyOrderBy, Int32 skip, Int32 take, Direction direction, 
Boolean distinct, Expression`1 where) in P:\Desenvolvimento\branchs\builder-3.0\Mandarim.Storage.Neo4j\Manager\ManagerBase.cs:line 2105\r\n   at 
Mandarim.Storage.Neo4j.Manager.ManagerBase`1.GetNodesRelatedOrderBy(String id, Labels labelin, Labels labelout, String relationTypes, String propertyOrderBy, Int32 skip, Int32 take, Boolean 
distinct, Expression`1 where, Direction direction) in P:\Desenvolvimento\branchs\builder-3.0\Mandarim.Storage.Neo4j\Manager\ManagerBase.cs:line 900\r\n   at 
Mandarim.Factory.Base.FactoryBase`1.GetNodesRelatedOrderBy(String id, Labels labelin, Labels labelout, String relationTypes, String propertyOrderBy, Int32 skip, Int32 take, Boolean distinct, 
Expression`1 where, Direction direction) in P:\Desenvolvimento\branchs\builder-3.0\Mandarim.Factory\Base\FactoryBase.cs:line 177\r\n   at 
PackDocs.Services.Storage.MandarimStorageServices`1.GetNodesRelatedOrderBy(String id, Labels labelin, Labels labelout, String propertyOrderBy, Int32 skip, Int32 take, Boolean distinct, 
Expression`1 where, Direction direction, RelationTypes[] relationNodeType) in P:\Desenvolvimento\branchs\builder-3.0\Packdocs.Services.Storage\MandarimStorageServices.cs:line 292\r\n
at Mandarim.PackDocs.Services.ManagerObjects.ManagerProject.GetProjects(Int32 skip, Int32 take, String orderby, CreatedState state) in 
P:\Desenvolvimento\branchs\builder-3.0\PackDocs.Services\ManagerObjects\ManagerProject.cs:line 116\r\n   at PackDocs.OWIN.Services.Host.Controllers.ProjectsController.GetProjects(Int32 
skip, Int32 take, String orderby, CreatedState state) in P:\Desenvolvimento\branchs\builder-3.0\Packdocs.OWIN.Services.Host\Controllers\v2\ProjectsController.cs:line 103\r\n   at 
lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object instance, Object[] 
methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken 
cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at 
System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at 
System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at 
System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown 
---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task 
task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"}

**Update**

```
            ContainerBuilder _builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            _builder
            .Register<ITransactionalGraphClient>(context =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var neo4jUri = GetNeo4jSettingValue("neo4jUri");
                    var user = GetNeo4jSettingValue("neo4jUser");
                    var pwd = GetNeo4jSettingValue("neo4jPassword");
                    ITransactionalGraphClient graphClient = new GraphClient(new Uri(neo4jUri), user, pwd);
                    graphClient.Connect();
                    graphClient.JsonConverters.Add(new DictionaryConverter());
                    graphClient.JsonConverters.Add(new DateTimeConverter());
                    graphClient.JsonConverters.Add(new CommonDeserializerMethods());


                    return graphClient;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Trace.TraceError(e.ToString());
                    throw e;
                }
            }).SingleInstance();

            _container = _builder.Build();
```

Get Instance

```
           try
            {
                _myGraphClient = _myGraphClient ?? AutofacNeo4j.Container.Resolve<ITransactionalGraphClient>();
                if (_myGraphClient != null && !_myGraphClient.IsConnected)
                    _myGraphClient.Connect();
                return _myGraphClient;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Trace.TraceError(e.ToString());
                _myGraphClient = _myGraphClient ?? AutofacNeo4j.Container.Resolve<ITransactionalGraphClient>();
                _myGraphClient.Connect();
                return _myGraphClient;
            }
```

My query:

```
                     MyGraphClient.Cypher
                    .Match(match).Where((T a) => a.UUID == id)
                    .With("b")
                    .CurrentUser(CurrentUsername)
                    .WhereReadClause("b", GetDomainsClause("b"),       CurrentUsername, CurrentRole, direction)
                    .Return(b => b.As<T>()).Results;
```

**Second exception:**

Neo4jClient.Transactions.TransactionManager.EnqueueCypherRequest(String commandDescription, IGraphClient graphClient, CypherQuery query) in D:\temp\9517fa3\Neo4jClient.Full\Transactions\TransactionManager.cs:line 229
   at Neo4jClient.GraphClient.PrepareCypherRequest[TResult](CypherQuery query, IExecutionPolicy policy) in D:\temp\9517fa3\Neo4jClient.Shared\GraphClient.cs:line 871
   at Neo4jClient.GraphClient.d__88`1.MoveNext() in D:\temp\9517fa3\Neo4jClient.Shared\GraphClient.cs:line 967
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Mandarim.Storage.Neo4j.Manager.ManagerBase`1.d__113.MoveNext() in P:\Desenvolvimento\branchs\builder-3.0\Mandarim.Storage.Neo4j\Manager\ManagerBase.cs:line 2067

Comment: Hi, can you provide the code you are using to call `Neo4jClient` and any data objects you are serializing? It's very hard to debug this (impossible) without those things!

Comment: @ChrisSkardon I update my ask with part of my code. Is very strange because the error occurs random. But I most time, is occurs in second request.

Thanks

Comment: @ChrisSkardon  Another exception I get in same case.

Comment: @ChrisSkardonI found the problem. I don't know why but the TransactionContext sometimes is null. In class TransactionManager method GetContext the return nonDtcTransaction.TransactionContext; is null. You have any Idea why this became null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs when we use async api with multi-transaction here.
The [TreadStartic] on Neo4jClient code don't work very well with async method... so I change to use AsyncLocal.

More information can get here: https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/pull/209